# elasticsearch get term frequency from not analyzed field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is it possible to get term frequency from an unanalyzed field? 
Like for field 
"text": {"type": "string","store": True,"index": "not_analyzed"}

I'm using the following query to get occurrence of a term

```
GET /manual_train/document/_search
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "text": {"value": "term"}}},"size": 10000}
```

My question is can I get term frequecy instead of occurrence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all ways i could imagine here are weird, except one, that will require creation of the elasticsearch REST plugin.

Comment: OK, thank you anyway, I will count it programmatically.